# Que hay mal en esta consulta sql?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, mysql-workbench

Tengo esta consulta en JavaFX para generar un pdf con iText, Pero me salta un error de que el documento no tiene paginas.

SQL:

```
SELECT fechakm, unidad, conductor, kmentrada, kmsalida, kmrecorrido FROM kilometraje WHERE ( unidad = ? AND  between fechakm = ? AND fechakm = ? )
```

Este es mi codigo Java:

```
public void Reporte1(String unidad, String fecha1, String fecha2, Connection connection){
    Document documento = new Document();
    try {
        String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "/Desktop/ReporteKmRecorridoPorUnidad.pdf"));
        documento.open();

        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(6);
        tabla.addCell("Fecha");
        tabla.addCell("Unidad");
        tabla.addCell("Conductor");
        tabla.addCell("KmEntrada");
        tabla.addCell("KmSalida");
        tabla.addCell("KmRecorrido");

        try {
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbase", "USER","PASS");
            Conexion.GetDatabaseConnection();
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT fechakm, unidad, conductor, kmentrada, kmsalida, kmrecorrido FROM kilometraje WHERE ( unidad = ? AND  between fechakm = ? AND fechakm = ? )");
            pst.setString(1, unidad);
            pst.setString(2, fecha1);
            pst.setString(3, fecha2);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                do {
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(1));
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(2));
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(3));
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(4));
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(5));
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(6));
                } while (rs.next());
                documento.add(tabla);
            }

        }catch(DocumentException | SQLException e)  {

        } documento.close();
            Alert mensaje = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            mensaje.setTitle("Tramesa");
            mensaje.setContentText("Reporte Generado Correctamente");
            mensaje.setHeaderText("Reporte");
            mensaje.show();
    } catch(DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
}

@FXML
public void AccionReporteRecoPorUnidad() {
    try{
        if(cb_unidad.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == -1){
            Alert alerta1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alerta1.setTitle("Tramesa");
            alerta1.setHeaderText("Campo vacio");
            alerta1.setContentText("Debe seleccionar una Unidad");
            alerta1.showAndWait();
        }else if(dp_fechaUni1.getValue()==null){
            Alert alerta1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alerta1.setTitle("Tramesa");
            alerta1.setHeaderText("Campo vacio");
            alerta1.setContentText("Debe seleccionar una Fecha Inicial");
            alerta1.showAndWait();
        }else if(dp_fechaUni2.getValue()== null){
            Alert alerta1 = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alerta1.setTitle("Tramesa");
            alerta1.setHeaderText("Campo vacio");
            alerta1.setContentText("Debe seleccionar una Fecha Final");
            alerta1.showAndWait();
        }else{
            SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            java.lang.String fechaInicio = formato.format(java.sql.Date.valueOf(dp_fechaUni1.getValue()));
            java.lang.String fechaFin = formato.format(java.sql.Date.valueOf(dp_fechaUni2.getValue()));
            Conexion.GetDatabaseConnection();
            Reporte1(cb_unidad.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString(), fechaInicio, fechaFin, Conexion.GetDatabaseConnection() );

        }


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Aqui mi tabla:
[image: Tabla MySQL]

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer tu consulta es errónea por como utilizaste BETWEEN. Su sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
... WHERE fecha BETWEEN valor1 AND valor2;
```

Por lo tanto, tu consulta debería ser la siguiente:

```
SELECT fechakm, unidad, conductor, kmentrada, kmsalida, kmrecorrido FROM kilometraje WHERE unidad = ? AND fechakm BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: Gracias ya lo habia solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo tengo!, Solo era un mal orden en la consulta.

```
SELECT fechakm, unidad, conductor, kmentrada, kmsalida, kmrecorrido FROM kilometraje WHERE  unidad = ? AND fechakm between   ? AND  ?
```